# How to update a field in the model later in the project with different form?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a model for registered users and added a field feedback in it. I need to allow logged in users to post feedback and to get it updated in the model, but it is not. Instead it is getting created as a new entry with a primary key.

model for register

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Roles, default='client')
    feedback = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    verified =models.BooleanField(default = False,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

form for feedback:

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('feedback',)
```

view for feedback:

```
@login_required
def feedback(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)


    else:
        form = FeedbackForm()

    if form.is_valid():
         userprofile=form.save(request)
         userprofile.save()
    else:
        form = FeedbackForm()
    return render(request, 'NewApp/feedback.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the current profile as the `instance` parameter.

```
    form = FeedbackForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
```